# How To Build an Animated Header in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem with a plugin. Took hours trying to find a solution but not this failing.

Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/NvU4D/2/
And look at this please: http://jsfiddle.net/NvU4D/5/

In the first link, everything works fine. But when I change the values ​​of the height of the image in the plugin there is a failure

```
 var imageHeight = 900;     // Background image height
```

when the image reaches the end of its animation should be repeated, but without making a jump. That is the mistake, there is a jump in the animation does not happen in the first link ... I don't understand why happen that.

Comment: Posting jsfiddles is fine and encouraged, but you should include relevant code in your post body as well.

Answer (score 1):

it's so logical that this is not working, change the height of the header div

```
var headerHeight = 200;
```

this one worked for me

the trick is, that you're mashing the picture when declaring its width to 900px. the picture is supposed to be 4300px therefore the animation flow is jumping when you set it to 900px

here the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NvU4D/10/

Comment: First, thanks a lot for your answer.. But it's just a patch. If you look closely and compare it with this:
http://jsfiddle.net/NvU4D/2/ 
There is a moment in your link that the image is repeated when you have to restart. Devido This is not right that specifies the height of the header. The height of the header would have to be anyone, 200px, 300px, 400px .. But however it only works well with the original measures.  var imageHeight = 4300; // Background image height
var headerHeight = 300;     // How tall the header is.          (Sorry for my English)

Comment: i know but as long as you are mashing the image from 4300 to 900 px, you wont see a fluent animation